# UIWebview: WebThread EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a completely simple app: Show a web view with http://tv2.dk

I'am using a storyboard, added the web view and set a property on my controller. To keep things simple i'am not setting a delegate.

In viewDidLoad i call the web view with the url i want to load

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tv2.dk"]]];
```

Each time the app starts up it crashes due to some error in a web thread worker, see this dump.

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x1954f7bc0:  cmp    x0, #0
0x1954f7bc4:  b.le   0x1954f7c30               ; objc_msgSend + 112
0x1954f7bc8:  ldr    x13, [x0]
0x1954f7bcc:  and    x9, x13, #0x1fffffff8
0x1954f7bd0:  ldp    x10, x11, [x9, #16]
0x1954f7bd4:  and    w12, w1, w11
0x1954f7bd8:  add    x12, x10, x12, lsl #4
0x1954f7bdc:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12]
0x1954f7be0:  cmp    x16, x1
0x1954f7be4:  b.ne   0x1954f7bec               ; objc_msgSend + 44
0x1954f7be8:  br     x17
0x1954f7bec:  cbz    x16, 0x1954f7d80          ; _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache
0x1954f7bf0:  cmp    x12, x10
0x1954f7bf4:  b.eq   0x1954f7c00               ; objc_msgSend + 64
0x1954f7bf8:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12, #-16]!
0x1954f7bfc:  b      0x1954f7be0               ; objc_msgSend + 32
0x1954f7c00:  add    x12, x12, w11, uxtw #4
0x1954f7c04:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12]
0x1954f7c08:  cmp    x16, x1
0x1954f7c0c:  b.ne   0x1954f7c14               ; objc_msgSend + 84
0x1954f7c10:  br     x17
0x1954f7c14:  cbz    x16, 0x1954f7d80          ; _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache
0x1954f7c18:  cmp    x12, x10
0x1954f7c1c:  b.eq   0x1954f7c28               ; objc_msgSend + 104
0x1954f7c20:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12, #-16]!
0x1954f7c24:  b      0x1954f7c08               ; objc_msgSend + 72
0x1954f7c28:  mov    x2, x9
0x1954f7c2c:  b      0x1954e1e70               ; objc_msgSend_corrupt_cache_error
0x1954f7c30:  b.eq   0x1954f7c48               ; objc_msgSend + 136
0x1954f7c34:  adrp   x10, 18278
0x1954f7c38:  add    x10, x10, #1904
0x1954f7c3c:  lsr    x11, x0, #60
0x1954f7c40:  ldr    x9, [x10, x11, lsl #3]
0x1954f7c44:  b      0x1954f7bd0               ; objc_msgSend + 16
0x1954f7c48:  movz   x1, #0
0x1954f7c4c:  movi   d0, #0000000000000000
0x1954f7c50:  movi   d1, #0000000000000000
0x1954f7c54:  movi   d2, #0000000000000000
0x1954f7c58:  movi   d3, #0000000000000000
0x1954f7c5c:  ret
```

Offending line

```
0x1954f7bd0:  ldp    x10, x11, [x9, #16]
```

Check out the full source code here: https://bitbucket.org/styrken/ios-webview-crash

I have tried running this code on multiple devices etc, crashes on them all.

Comment: Try to call loadRequest: in viewWillAppear:, maybe it will help.

Comment: It does not work to put the code in either viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. Same results.

Comment: I have found out that with using NSZombie's, i got the following crash message: WebviewCrash[4598:956679] *** -[UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1707c5370. To fix this i had to turn off animations in UIVIew using [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; and now it works. It seems like a bug in iOS8.

Comment: Dang @RasmusStyrk that's amazing. How did you find that? We couldn't figure out the problem for the life of us!  I'm going to copy this into an answer so it's more obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From @RasmusStyrk 's comment above

> I have found out that with using NSZombie's, i got the following crash
>   message: WebviewCrash[4598:956679] *** -[UIViewAnimationState
>   release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1707c5370. To fix
>   this i had to turn off animations in UIVIew using [UIView
>   setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; and now it works. It seems like a bug in
>   iOS8. –

We also had this where it would randomly crash, and setting [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO] is the only thing that has worked to completely alleviate this issue!

Comment: Yep. I'am pretty sure it's a bug. Anyway - You can turn off the animations or use the new WKWebview class.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS` says it all. 
UIWebView likes to be called from the main thread. Try putting your code as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 //send webview a message 
 [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tv2.dk"]]];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made the silly mistake to forget adding the WKWebView to the view hierarchy prior to loading a resource.